# Achieving sub millisecond latency with gRPC over LAN?

Tags: java, http, tcp, grpc, benchmarking

I was reading about the performance of `gRPC` and found [a couple of interesting benchmarks](https://www.nexthink.com/blog/comparing-grpc-performance/):

`gRPC` is capable of processing approx. 36K requests per second using a single core server and approx. 62K requests per second using two cores (using the `Java` implementation).

[image]

When it comes to latency we're looking at *77ms* for *p99* which is not acceptable when sub millisecond latency is required.

[image]

I thought the latency/throughput can be improved dramatically when two or more servers communicate over the same network.

Does `gRCP` open a **local** `TCP` connection by default when available? Can I assume the latency/throughput would be dramatically faster than the benchmarks shown in such cases?

Thanks

Comment: It is a bit hard to tell via a quick skim and without p50, but it seems the linked benchmark used a single benchmark and measured both throughput and latency. That's fundamentally broken as to find throughput limit you need to saturate which will have poor latency. The official gRPC benchmarks show ~130µs for a noop RPC on an unloaded TLS connection over a local network. https://grpc.io/docs/guides/benchmarking/